# group by join table column with has_many association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

below are my relationship

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
    end

    # Table name: orders
    #  id               :integer          not null, primary key
    #  status           :string(255)
    #  total_cost       :integer          default(0)
    #  user_id          :integer
    #  created_at       :datetime
    #  updated_at       :datetime

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

I tried to list user with their order count. for expected output

```
 {"user1@gmail.com"=>3, "user1@gmail.com"=>2, "user1@gmail.com"=>1}
```

I tried the following

```
User.joins(:orders).group("orders.users.id").count
```

and got the following as output(key as user id,value as order count)

```
{2=>3, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```

how to replace the key with user email and value as number of order counts?

Comment: I dont' see which table contains the email

Comment: Try `User.joins(:orders).group("orders.users.email").count`

Comment: User table @PhilipDevine

Answer (score 1):

Is this working for you ?

```
Hash[User.includes(:orders).map{|u| [u.email, u.orders.count ]}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ugo Mare. It works but too many database call for each user. any ways thanks for the solution

Comment: Not with a counter cache column, this will add a a column to user and each times you create or destroy an order it will be incremented of decremented. In your case it should be the best solution.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: So it will be smthg like 
`Hash[User.all.map{|u| [u.email, u.orders_count ]}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
User.joins(:orders).group(:email).count
```

See the "Total of grouped items" section in the [Group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) documentation in the RailsGuides.  You will want to make sure you have a unique constraint on the `email` column.